# Solr outputs the value of another field in one field

Tags: java, spring-boot, indexing, solr, full-text-search

There is a project on `Spring Boot` and `Solr`. There is an `Employee` entity that has the `Work Phone` and `MobilePhone` fields. The data is stored in the `Employee` table, respectively, from `PostgreSQL`. When searching through a `Solr` worker, everything is displayed correctly, except for `mobilePhone`. The value from the `workPhone` is somehow passed to `mobilePhone`. Why?

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz1zn.png)

[work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBFEq.png)

Employee

```java
@SolrDocument(collection = "employee")
public class EmployeeIndex {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7591758092960218296L;

    @Field("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Field("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Field("middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Field("work_phone")
    private String workPhone;

    @Field("mobile_phone")
    private List<String> mobilePhone;
}
```

Repository

```java
public interface EmployeeIndexRepository extends BasicIndexRepository<EmployeeIndex> {

    EmployeeIndex findFirstByLogin(String login);
}
```

```java
 <copyField source="work_phone"                      dest="_text_"/>
    <copyField source="mobile_phone"                    dest="_text_"/>

<copyField source="work_phone"                      dest="text_highlight"/>
    <copyField source="mobile_phone"                    dest="text_highlight"/>

<copyField source="work_phone"                      dest="text_spell"/>
    <copyField source="mobile_phone"                    dest="text_spell"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any copyField-entries in your Solr schema?

Comment: yes. I add in question

Comment: Are you sure that `mobilePhone` hasn't received the value from `workPhone` as well before being sent to Solr?

Comment: No, because in database table I have enum type of phony type with @OneToMany relationsip in Java-code.